# MSIE Browser Detect: Missing Radix?

Tags: jquery, browser-detection

```
if($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) < 9) {}
```

Jshint says it's missing the radix. I'm not sure how I would write that?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `parseInt($.browser.version, 10)`. The ', 10' tells `parseInt` to use base-10.

**EDIT:**
In most circumstances, the default behavior of parseInt is to treat the input as base-10, so you can get away with not including the radix. However, if you're converting from a string that has a leading zero, parseInt treats the value as an octal (base-8) number if you don't tell it what base to use, so you get this:
`parseInt("07") == 7`

`parseInt("08") == 0`

`parseInt("010") == 8`

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @Yahreen:

Thanks for the answers everyone. I have found this validates:

```
if (jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version < 9){
    //do something
}
```